# An Android App for blocking trackers completely using AI

Tags: privacy, google-play-services, gps-tracking, open-source, xprivacy

***About my device:***

- **Android version:** 10
- **ROM:** Stock ROM(Android One)
- **Bootloader status:** Unlocked and Rooted with Magisk 21.4 Stable

***Tweaks that I've done till today:***

- AdAway
- AfWall+
- Warden
- Ditched Chrome for Bromite, Brave(for syncing to pc) and Firefox Klar
- [NUKED script](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/module-tool-nuked_script-tm-b-attery-p-erformance-p-rivacy.4131715/)
- And many more!

I'm currently searching for an Android app that can block **ALL** the **trackers** as well as **hidden trackers** on Android including **Ads**.
I, being a privacy enthusiast, have done a lot of online search, and currently using an open source app called **[Warden](https://www.xda-developers.com/warden-open-source-app-aurora-store-disable-trackers-loggers/)**. It's good but, user needs to spend ton of time tweaking apps for better protection against trackers.
*(If you're from India and you use **Jio sim**, then you'll have **MyJio** installed, their tracking is literally **insane**!)*.
I'd like know, is there any other Android App that can **learn** to **tweak and disable** trackers(privacy badger extension for browsers, for example) on it's own as the time passes, just like how Google Keyboard learns to personalize the dictionary.

Editings and Suggestions are always welcome:)

Comment: It is not necessary to use MyJio app to use a Jio SIM, but it is sort of very hard to keep track of real-time mobile data in its absence (JIO doesn't provide handy USSD codes).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I use it for keeping track of my data usage and recharge purposes. And yes, I just used it as an example for better clarification of what Im trying to say.

Comment: If you want "100% tracker freeness" you need to use the reverse approach. Do not blacklist trackers, instead white-list required domains. An AI is IMHO not a solution as you would have to train it first and afterwards a new tracker that just acts totally different as the others will not be detected as the AI is not trained on it. Additionally such an AI would require full data access (not only the domain names because from those you can't lern much) and therefore the AI would have to process a lot of data which also means that it would waste a lot of battery.

Comment: Got you! @Robert, I agree with your point of not using an AI related app for such thing, but do any app that exist to whitelist the required domains for required apps to work? or any scriptfor getting my job done. Because, Warden, that I've been using since months, is good, but it misses most of the **amazing** trackers by libraries(not sure if that;s a library) like Madme and others, especially _adtriggers_.

Comment: After struggling for a long time to achieve the same, what I ended up with is to simply use DNS blocking combined with app blocking. Block all the apps (using `iptables` or VPN based solutions) you think should not go online. But be aware of the fact that UID based blocking won't work if an app is using GMS APIs (and you haven't blocked Play Services). For the apps going online DNS blocking works quite good, even for malware protection on Windows. Keep the `hosts` file updated e.g. with StevenBlacks's. Even better, I use `dnscrypt` which encrypts (to prevent DNS hijacking) as well as blocks.

Comment: So, @IrfanLatif, in my case, **AdAway**(AdAway official Hosts, Bromite Filters, Pete Lowe Blocklist Hosts and StevenBlack Unified Hosts) and AfWall+ is more than enough? Along with Warden? But still, Jio related apps show a ton of Ads in it's apps(and they now feels like Adwares!).

Comment: Well the definition of *"more than enough"* may vary for persons. It depends on how concerned you are about your privacy. And honestly saying, the pace at which tracking, ads, malware, ransomware etc. are evolving, nothing is more than enough. So it's a matter of satisfaction, depending on one's technical acumen. Majority of the Android users in not aware of and not concerned about what Google alone is doing to them.

Comment: On the other side there are people like me. I've customized my device with root privileges - some native services running in background - to make it as secure and private as possible. For sensitive data like contacts, photos and notes I've developed some minimal apps of my own to avoid dependency on third party resources. But still I think there are a number of aspects of privacy missing in my setup.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with your point of view, me, so, what I'm currently doing is using FOSS apps(most of them) that mostly works offline except for contacts as Google Backup of contacts is a must for me.
[Edit:] And I don't know what would happen if I apply firewall to GMS. Apps that depends upon GMS, might stop working. That's the only fear that I've.